# Rails: How to model items with multiple tags, where some tags are required?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to model items that `has_many` tags. Items can have multiple tags, but are required to have at least 3 predefined ones.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :type, :through => :item_tags, :source => :tag
  has_one :material, :through => :item_tags, :source => :tag
  has_one :use, :through => :item_tags, :source => :tag
  has_many :tag, :through => :item_tags
  has_many :item_tags
end
```

This is giving me an `ActiveRecord::HasOneThroughCantAssociateThroughCollection` when I try to do Item.find(1).type.

I'm not sure how to do this. Can anyone help?

EDIT: I also want to be able to find the three predefined tags by doing item.type and item.use etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to consider this first by seeing how you want your database set up.  You want:

Table: Tag

- id
- tag_name

Table: ItemTag

- id
- item_id
- tag_id

Table: Item

- id
- type_id
- material_id
- use_id

So, your model would be more like:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type, :class_name => 'Tag'
  belongs_to :material, :class_name => 'Tag'
  belongs_to :use, :class_name => 'Tag'

  # Require these tags
  validates_presence_of :type, :material, :use

  has_many :item_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :item_tags

  def list_tags
    [type, material, use] + tags
  end
end
```

So, your database will have three columns directly in the item table, which link to the tag table.  These are required via validations, but you can also set up in your migrations to make these columns not null as well if you wish.  The other optional tags keep their same relationship.

You want belongs_to and not has_one, because that pushes the relationship to the Item, where you want it.  Has_one puts an item_id column in the Tag table, which is not what you want.

To get the three required tags to appear with the rest of the tags via this method, I'd recommend adding a function just for this use, defined as list_tags above.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is really close to what I want, but I'm also looking for the type, material, and use tags to be added to the whole list of tags. This does get me item.type etc, but when I do item.tag to get the list of all the tags, those three don't show up. Is this possible to do, or will I just need to manually return those three when I run item.tag?

Comment: I guess I could add a validation that checks to see if type, material, and use are already tags in item.tag yet, and if not, add them there.

Comment: Yeah, you could also do that, but probably not necessary.  If you went that route, though, you could do that via a before_save or after_save callback in the model.  You could opt to use the list_tags function I edited in above.  I named it that instead of overriding tags as that can be an ordeal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to use custom validations to check that Item.tags includes the ones you require, then use either scopes and class methods to get item.use, item.type, etc. to work as you want.

Item model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :class_name => 'ItemTag'

  validate :has_type, :has_use, :has_material

  # Access methods
  def types
    self.tags.types
  end
  def uses
    self.tags.uses
  end
  def materials
    self.tags.materials
  end

  private

  # Custom validation methods
  def has_type
    unless tags.present? and tags.include?(ItemTag.types)
      errors.add("Tags must include a type.")
    end
  end

  def has_material
    unless tags.present? and tags.include?(ItemTag.materials)
      errors.add("Tags must include a material.")
    end
  end

  def has_use
    unless tags.present? and tags.include?(ItemTag.use)
      errors.add("Tags must include a use.")
    end
  end
end
```

ItemTag model:

```
class ItemTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :types, lambda { where(...) }
  scope :materials, lambda { where(...) }
  scope :uses, lambda { where(...) }
end
```

You could grab single occurances if preferred using `.first` in the access methods. You'll need to adjust the `where(...)` queries based on how you are determining what constitutes a type/material/use.